# Analog of codomain and image in context of relations

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, relations

I was reviewing [relations and functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations) and I came across the definition *serial* which is new to me. This more or less throws a wrench in what I thought I understood and I'm seeking clarity.

If I think of this in terms of mapping one ellipse to another, then I understood the left ellipse to be the *domain* and the right ellipse to be the *codomain*. The relation mapping the *domain* to the *codomain* does not have to cover the full *codomain*, where the part that it does cover is the *image* (or *range*). This is basically a nested ellipse in the *codomain*, where if the ellipses are the "same", then the relation is *surjective*.

Going back to my opening acknowledgment with the use of *serial*, it sounds like there is a nested analog of *image* for the left ellipse? In other words, to just call the left ellipse the *domain* is incorrect? There should be "parent-child" ellipses, in which one of them is the *domain*? Based on the names, intuition says the analog of *codomain* is *domain*, but then what is the analog of *image*?

From what I see in the link above, it sounds like *serial* means that the left ellipses are the "same", which admittedly is what I assumed all along. If the relation is not *serial*, then we have a distinction between *domain* and ?

Comment: Stupid term.  Left total is meaningful.

Comment: I found a figure here which clearly shows what I'm asking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra) This discussion is specific to "kernels" of linear algebra. I'm wondering if there is a general concept of "kernels" in the context of relations? What do we call these general concepts?

Comment: Nuisances......

Comment: @WilliamElliot it sounds like you are suggesting that there is no general concept of a "kernel"?